# Migrating SVN repository to Git

Tags: git, svn

I'm migrating from SVN repository to Git, basically following this steps:

1. git svn init [URL] --no-metadata
2. git svn fetch

When I tested the migrate process, I used this URL http://teach-me.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/, it has about 270 commits. But, when I tried migrate the SVN repo, with 6 months old and 800 commits; of client company, it returned an error. I'm using Git 1.9.4 on Windows, SNV on Windows too.
Someone had this problem too?

[image]

Comment: You'll probably have better luck if you paste the text content of the error instead of a tiny, hard to read image.

Comment: Chris, sorry for the image, but are many sensitivy information on screen to share

Answer (score 0):

http://randomallsorts.blogspot.com/2011/10/using-git-svn-with-large-repository.html seems to have a good answer: "We need to load in batches. git fetch has a -r option to allow you to specify the range of revisions to fetch. We've got some large files, so we'll do 10 at a time."

```
git svn clone https://[redacted]m:8443 --stdlayout -r1:2
```